# How will X509-validated payments request work? (AKA "The Payment Protocol")

Tags: bitcoin-core, payment, bip70-payment-protocol

I'm looking for an overview and requirements on how this will work... including

- Root CA selection (across the platforms)
- What does the request look like?
- How does the payment "flow" look like?

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of the [Bitcoin Payment Protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Payment_Request) (seen in [BIP 070](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0070))  is to provide for a better customer experience and better security against man-in-the-middle attacks on the payment process.

See this [BitcoinTalk announcment](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=300809.msg3225143#msg3225143) and information from [the Bitcoin Foundation](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/blog/?p=290).  The code for this is located in the [PaymentServer.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/qt/paymentserver.cpp) file

> How are Root CAs selected?

Root CAs are selected from [this Mozilla root CA list.](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/included/)  Although I haven't seen anything to verify this, but I hope there is a way to account for Certificate "extended key usage" in the PKI hierarchy.

> What does the request process look like?

No GUI screenshot of this process is available (yet), but a workflow of the process looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example bitcoin: url?